# Streamreader Line with commas into a dictionary

Tags: c#, text-files, streamreader, split

I have a text file that contains lines and each line is seperated with a comma.
I want to put the data on the dictionary that will get the key and value based on the text file's values that are seperated in comma on each line.

txt row example:

```
{
key, value
}
```

I first get the data in a loop. If it was simply a string then i would know how to do it but the fact that i am firstly reading it from a streamReader it gives me problems. In a normal list it also worked but in this method it just doesn't work on the dictionary. Here is the code:

```
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("Text.txt");
string line;
int i = 0;

while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    string[] arr = line.Split(',');
    dict.Add(arr[i], arr[i + 1]);
    i= i+2;                             
}
```

I got stuck in the `dict.Add` . I know it shouldn't be the arr as i wrote.
Thanks for any help!

Comment: How you have defined the dictionary ? What is the exact error you are getting ? and are you sure you are getting at least 2 elements returned in your array after split ?

Comment: Do you mean `i = i + 2` or `i += 2`? Currently `i` is always `0`

Comment: The dictionary is <string, string>. Exactly as the template of the TXT file.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is almost impossibly unclear. But from what I could decipher, you either need another while loop:

```
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("Text.txt");
string line;

while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    string[] arr = line.Split(',');
    int i = 0;
    while (i < arr.Length)
    {
        dict.Add(arr[i], arr[i + 1]);
        i+=2;  
    }                           
}
```

Or your need forget about your `i` variable entirely:

```
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("Text.txt");
string line;

while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    string[] arr = line.Split(',');
    dict.Add(arr[0], arr[1]);                         
}
```

One of those should be right. Which one depends on whether you have multiple sets of values per line or not. The text of your question makes this impossible to guess.

And fwiw, string.Split() is usually a really horrible way to handle comma-separated data.

Comment: Hello, I am still a beginner in programming. Thanks for your reply. What would you suggest to use that is better?

Comment: @SnookerBall A dedicated csv parser. There are a number out there, and there is even one included with the .Net framework (Microsoft.VisualBasic.TextFieldParser)

Comment: The first code you wrote is what i tried to do even before but it always gave me this message:
"An unhandled exception of type 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException' occurred in ConsoleApplication25.exe" . The text file contains a lot of rows, and in each row there are words that are seperated with one comma in each line.